# terminating the password prompt during scp in perl after certain amount of time

Tags: perl, scp

I am trying exit the password input prompt  during a scp command in the perl script after certain amount time for the server which do not have the ssh public key. In this script, I am using the back-tick for copying of file from one server to another, but the script get stuck on the password prompt and do not exit out even after the assigned timeout.

```
my $test       = '';
my $exit_value = '';
eval {
          my $timeout = 2;
          local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "timeout\n" };
          alarm($timeout);
          $test       = `scp foo.txt bar@baz:/`;
          $exit_value = $? >> 8;
          alarm(0);
     }

if ($@) {
    print "Time out";
}
```

Is there any way handle the above scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the use of `IPC::Run` [module](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.94/lib/IPC/Run.pm) to achieve the above object, to terminate the password prompt after certain time.

So my current code looks like this

```
my $in  = '';
my $out = '';
my $err = '';
my @cmd = ('scp' , 'foo.txt' , 'bar@baz:/');

eval {
        run \@cmd, \$in, \$out, \$err,IPC::Run::timeout(5)
            or die "SSH Error: $? $err\n";
    };
if ($@) {
   print "TimeOut";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set BatchMode when calling from an non interactive session to disable the password prompt altogether.

```
$test = `scp -o BatchMode=yes foo.txt bar@baz:/`;
```

See below

```
 BatchMode
         If set to ``yes'', passphrase/password querying will be disabled.
         This option is useful in scripts and other batch jobs where no
         user is present to supply the password.  The argument must be
         ``yes'' or ``no''.  The default is ``no''.
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use the following parameter to disable the host_key checking using:-

> $test = scp -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no foo.txt bar@baz:/;